# Protect deeplink to unauthorized company

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multi-tenant application with Companies which have many Users and many Clients. 
I have protected the views and controllers with before_filters, so that the current_user can only view clients belonging to the user's company. This works fine, an unauthorized user receives a "you do not have sufficient rights for this action" message. But when a user changes the URL from e.g. "/clients/1/edit" to "clients/2/edit", then he can edit a client from another company. What's the best way to protect this?

Answer (score 0):

Expand your strategy to protect the `clients` controller as well - you need to be checking ownership of a client record on every action, since only some people should be able to access some clients.

You should be able to continue with whatever solution you've got. Another way to go about it is to use something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), which centralizes access, and can make it much easier and more straight forward to debug (and more importantly, confirm via your test suite) that users only have access to what they should have access to.

[Here is a list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authorization) of common/popular authorizations gems for Rails that address problems of user access to resources.

Whatever approach you ultimately choose, I can't stress enough how important it is to cover things like security access with test coverage. It's never perfect (because you might forget to test something), but it will mitigate the possibility that you break security access restrictions that are already in place, by keeping your security-related tests as up-to-date as humanly possible.